# How to freely/plain text edit the hex values in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, hexadecimal, hex-editor

In notepad++ there's a plugin called `Hex Editor`

That plugin helps you to edit and read hex files `.bin` files in notepad++ without third-party software

my question is :

How can i edit the values without the address or the dump of the hex file just like a plain text

in notepad++ hex editor plugin -- it only edit one block at the time i want to edit them like a string / a plain text
freely not block by block

is it possible ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there a way to view hex values as plain text ? in notepad++ or any light weghit IDE](https://superuser.com/questions/1666777/is-there-a-way-to-view-hex-values-as-plain-text-in-notepad-or-any-light-wegh)

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations - so i specified notepad++

Comment: If you don't like the notepad++ Hex Editor plugin, you need a real hex editor.

Comment: `it only edit one block at the time` coz that is how notepad++ core engine works, edit 1 character at a time.. The next closest thing I can suggest to implement what u need, is to use/edit/compile ur action using the notepad++ macro & run it. hope this helps ( :